# how to know if a list of word are in the dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of words like this

```
                       name
                      [primevère]
  [one, federal, credit, union]
                      [nitroxal]
```

and I have a dictionary called words. words contain all English words in the English dictionary. Format like below

```
**word**
data
name
english...
```

For one, federal, credit, union, I want to test each element is in the dictionary

```
df['is_english'] = df['name'].isin(words)
df.head(3)
```

however, for list like this, [one, federal, credit, union], I won't be able to cover everything. I want to see if each element in the list is an English word. If one of them not english, return false. If all words are english, return True.

Comment: What is the format of the dictionary?

Comment: The format is a pandas dataframe. word is the col name, below are all words

Comment: `all(word in database for word in word_list)`?

Comment: ' If one of them not english, return false. If all words are english, return True'.  Have a look at the builtin `all()` and comprehensions.  specifically something like `all(x in english_wds for x in wds)` will do the logic.  Then you've just got to .apply() it over your df

Comment: could you elaborate on this a little bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a working example of using `apply` to check whether all items in a list in the dataframe's `name` column are in the list `words`:

```
import pandas as pd

words = ['data','name','english']
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': [['primevère'],['one', 'federal', 'credit', 'union'],['english'],['nitroxal']]})
df['is_english'] = df['name'].apply(lambda wds: all(x in words for x in wds))
```

Result:

|  | name | is_english |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ['primevère'] | False |
| 1 | ['one', 'federal', 'credit', 'union'] | False |
| 2 | ['english'] | True |
| 3 | ['nitroxal'] | False |